# Split string from text file

Tags: c#, string, split, system.io.file

I'm trying to convert string to keys from a text file and I need to split text.
For example: 
Code c#

```
 string[] controls = File.ReadAllLines(FilePath);
 Keys move up = (Keys)Enum.Parse(type of(Keys),controls[1].Split("|", StringSplitOption.None), true);
```

---

In the text file at the line[1] I have :
 moveUp |W;

I want to set the char W as keys.

Thanks to reply and sorry if my English looks weird.

Comment: Thanks to reply, but i know  about index value. I tried as you wrote bit or doesn't work, can't compile. (Can't convert "string" to "string[]") so I made another string array but i got more errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested in string after **|** , then this should be:

```
controls[1].Split("|", StringSplitOption.None)
```

replaced with this:

```
controls[1].Split("|")[1]
```

`[1]` means return the 2nd index value from array which will be created by `Split()`

If you are trying to get from Line 1 then `controls[1]` should be `controls[0]` because arrays are zero index based.

Comment: Your solution didn't work perfectly, but it helped me to solved, replace controls[1].Split("|", StringSplitOption.None)[1] with string test = controls.Split('|')[1];

Comment: @Newokmyne edited my post , so may help others coming at this post